# How to enable the Native Library in OsmAnd?

Tags: osmand

In a 2012 thread about a case of OsmAnd being slow at rendering, one person advises this:

> verify that you use Native Library (which definitely speed up rendering process)

And the replies seems to imply it works:

> I selected the Native Library and deleted Ind.cache file. It has nearly doubled the rendering speed of my map.

I have the same problem of slow rendering, but I can't find the Native Library setting.

**QUESTION:** How to enable the Native Library in recent OsmAnd?

I am using [OsmAnd~ 1.8.3 from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus):

[image: OsmAnd development preferences]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To activate native rendering go into `Settings/OsmAnd development/Use native rendering (Use C++ rendering instead of Java)`

**Edit**: I've added a screenshot from OsmAnd+ 1.9.2g

[image: Screenshot of OsmAnd+ 1.9.2g preferences]

Comment: I don't seem to have this option, see screenshot.

Comment: Which version of OsmAnd are you using?

Comment: OsmAnd~ 1.8.3 from F-Droid

Comment: Installing 1.9.2g revealed that option.

Answer (score 1):

OsmAnd 2.4.7 doesn't have "OsmAnd development" under Settings, but Settings / General / Safe mode (Java rather than native code) is off by default.  Rendering is still slower than other OSM-based apps though.

Edit: the OpenGL flag on this version is under Plugins / OsmAnd Development / Settings / Use OpenGL Rendering.  Still doesn't seem to help much though (on Sony Xperia Z Ultra running Android 4.4)